# error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed

Tags: javascript, iframe, babeljs, babel-polyfill

My JavaScript is using [babel-polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/). I am using a Plug-In like Single-Page-Application. Now someone implemented another Plug-In and gets an error, because he is using `babel-polyfill` too.

> error: only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed

I have seen many posts on the internet about it. Solutions like

```
if (!global._babelPolyfill) {
   require('babel-polyfill');
}
```

But I think the code gets generated by `webpacker` and it feels hacked to modifiy the output. Is there maybe a configuration for this or would I have to use something like a powershell script as task to do this?

Other solutions were like use `babel-polyfill` only in your main-application - where the Plug-Ins get loaded. But in my case the host application shouldn't know about `babel-polyfill`. Also both Plug-Ins can be installed together, but don't have to.

Now i could try

- `babel-runtime`, but I dont want to change my whole code to match [babel-runtime](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-runtime/). Also i don't know if the other author is willing to change his code too.
- `iframe`, but i think it is difficult to handle the communication between my backend and the content of the `iframe`.

Any solutions ?

Comment: Did you solve the problem?